# Photoshop background not properly filling

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I am trying to fill background layer with gradient, but its not properly filling.
I have attached the screen shot for the same. Also in layer thumbnail it show white lines,
I don't know what happened, it was working fine suddenly it is behaving like this ! Any help ?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I guess it's a bug, Try to reset your **preferences**.

Goto **Edit menu > Preferences > General > Reset Preferences on quit** >
Restart Photoshop

**Method 2**

Try updating Photoshop version